# Using Expression Engine on a local host and getting a database error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, expressionengine

I backed up my website and installed it on my local machine using xampp. Well, after creating a database and connecting it, I ran into this error

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'mysql.exp_sites' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`exp_sites`) WHERE `site_id` = 1

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\sitecontrol\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

I have looked into the database and this query exists and also the data. I don't know what to do to resolve it

Comment: `mysql.exp_sites` means you have a table called `exp_sites` in the database called `mysql`. Please confirm if this is your actual database schema. if not you need to change your database connection settings.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, mysql have a table called exp_sites and also the content exists in the database for this table.

Comment: can you share the screenshots of the exp_site table of the database and db connection code of database.php?

Comment: @ZealousWeb sorry, i don't have it anymore